# Show the bottom of a scrollable element, instead of default top

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

How can you make an element with a scrollbar start off at the bottom of the scroll?

I have a `div` that has `overflow: scroll`. When the element is loaded, by default, we see the top of the element and you have to scroll down. I want the view to start at the bottom of the `div` instead.

JS fiddle example. Goal is to load the bottom element by default:

http://jsfiddle.net/2WpQf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use javascript, then you may do this (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2WpQf/1/):

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Jquery Plugin called ScrollTo, which can scroll for you progamatically.

[ScrollTo()](http://flesler.blogspot.in/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)